# if statement many values check for same source, without repeated source

Tags: javascript

```
if(document.getElementById('TheId').value (>=5 && <=6))
{
//code here
}
```

instead of:

```
if(document.getElementById('TheId').value >=5 && document.getElementById('TheId').value <=6)
{
//code here
}
```

can this work ?! , and why not they make the condition easy like this because it points to the same source , any information ?

Comment: **No**. Best you can do is `var v = document.getElementById('TheId').value;` and then `if (v == 5 || v == 6)`. Also, JavaScript is **not** Java or PHP.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah i know , but it's the same idea for all lanuages ..

Comment: Every language is different, that's kind of the point, however, they do tend to follow C like conventions, especially when it comes to doing `if` style statements (not always, but you get the idea).  In Java, each comparison must evaluate to true or false, which requires that each statement must be inherently comparable, which is where the complexity comes in, how do you adopt this to things like `String` or `Object`?

Comment: You're also asking a broad spectrum question about language design that only the original authors would have any hope of answering, but I would suspect that the answer would generally be the same, because it was the easiest solution to implement which covered the largest possible range of use-cases ... of course, now we're venturing into "opinion" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The condition *can* be written easily like that, you just have to extract the value to another variable first. Also, since `.value` returns a *string*, you probably want to cast it to a number first, just so that nothing unexpected occurs:

```
const value = Number(document.getElementById('TheId'));
if (value >= 5 && value <= 6) {
  // do something
}
```

If you wanted to put it all inside the `if` parentheses, you *could*, but it would look *really ugly*, since you'd have to use the unintuitive comma operator:

```
if ((value = Number(document.getElementById('TheId')), (value >= 5 && value <= 6)) {
  // do something
}
```

(much better to put the value into a variable beforehand)

I suppose another method would be to define two functions for testing the value, and check that `every`one of the functions passes when passed the value:

```
if (
  [val => val >= 5, val => val <= 6]
    .every(
      test => test(Number(document.getElementById('TheId'))
    )
  )
{
  // do something
}
```

But putting the value into a variable beforehand makes much more sense.